# Pushing back a pointer into a vector c++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

This is a follow up to [Using vectors to store different objects inherited from the same parent class c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022035/using-vectors-to-store-different-objects-inherited-from-the-same-parent-class-c) but you don't need to read it to understand.

I have a polynomial class and another class that is a container class. In the container class there is a vector that holds pointers to polynomials.
I have defined vectorPolynomial this way:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Polynomial>> vectorPolynomial;
```

In the polynomial class there is a binary operator that do an operation that takes two polynomials and returns the result which is a polynomial itself.

Before polymorphism the operator returned an object of type Polynomial and I just did this:

```
Polynomial polynomialresult = polynomial1 % polynomial2;
vectorPolynomial.push_back(polynomialresult);
```

Now since the vector is not a vector of polynomials anymore, this won't work. Here is what I tried:

```
std::unique_ptr<Polynomial> result(new Polynomial);
*result = *(vectorPolynomial[i]) % *(vectorPolynomial[j]);
vectorPolynomial.emplace_back(result);
```

This didn't work. I also tried:

```
Polynomial * result = new Polynomial;
```

instead of the unique_ptr but it didn't work either. push_back instead of emplace_back does not work either.

How is this typically done?

Answer (score 4):

`unique_ptr` has no copy constructor.  So you need to move it:

```
vectorPolynomial.emplace_back(std::move(result));
```

Comment: rror C2248: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=Polynomial

Comment: @jazzybazz: Please provide a more complete example of the code that is producing that error.

Answer (score 1):

While Benjamin’s amendment to your code works I feel that it’s a bit backwards. After all, `unique_ptr` hasn’t got a copy constructor for a good reason; your code could benefit from using normal objects rather than pointers:

```
Polynomial polynomialresult = *vectorPolynomial[i] % *vectorPolynomial[j];
vectorPolynomial.emplace_back(new Polynomial(polynomialresult));
```

Here we manually allocate memory only when we actually need to, no sooner.